# Internacionalização de imagens

Tags: javascript, localização

Eu tenho um projeto em HTML que necessita de imagens diferentes para cada linguagem.

A imagem é carregada no próprio index.html com `<img src="">`. Como trocar a imagem de acordo com o idioma escolhido?

Tentei esse código:

```
"img1": { 
     "pt": '../img/img-pt.jpg',
     "en": '../img/img-en.jpg', 
}
```

Comment: depende de como você desenvolveu o sistema, se for só html, eu criaria um select com as duas linguagens, e depois criaria uma função em javascript para ler esse select e definir qual imagem usar.

Comment: @Lodi estou usando apenas html e js, com o n18i.js que tem  propriedades de tradução de textos, porem tentei sem sucesso usar a mesma logica, como explanei na pergunta.

Comment: nunca ouvi falar nesse n18i, mas levando tudo em consideração, acredito que o que você deva fazer é construir uma função em javascript para mudar as imagens, conforme a linguagem muda! faça com Jquery você pega o elemento, e muda o atributo src para o desejado!

Answer (score 0):

Estava desde a postagem desta pergunta trabalhando na minha solução, até consegui-lá
segue o link do projeto - Click [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/djmarlonas10/project/editor/XMjymb#)